# Spring: How to properly create a new project from a local boilerplate project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

### My Environment:

- Java 8
- Gradle 4.x
- Spring Boot 2.1.x
- IntelliJ IDEA 2020
- A boilerplate project

### What I want to do

I'm a Flask developer new to Spring, please bear with me.
I want to create a new project from my boilerplate project.
with new group id, new package name. Does IntelliJ support this kind of task?
Or What usually fellow Spring developers do in this kind of situation?

### What I did

I found some boiler project on github, but couldn't find step by step guide to
rename or recreating the project.

### What I did 2 (edited)

I also looked up for spring initializer. but I need more than that! I have a boilerplate which there is some oauth2 code and test code in it. is there any way to create a new project from my **exisiting local project**?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a project using Intellij.

1. Go to *File -> New -> Project*

[image]

2. New Project popup will open. From that select `Spring initializr` and click `Next`.

[image]

3. In next next screen you will be provided with something like below. You ca play around with options according to your needs. Click `Next` once done.

[image]

4. In the next screen you will have options to choose the starter spring-boot dependencies. Choose the one you are interested in and click `Next`.

[image]

5. In the next screen choose the project name and location and click `Finish`. And you are done.

[image]

Comment: Can you accept the answer. If it was helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Well... thanks for the answer but unfortunately spring initiallizer was not exactly I was looking for... could you guide me the way to create a project form exisitng local project?

Comment: Sure i can do that. Share the GitHub  link to existing local project if it's on GitHub. If you don't have no issues. I will explain by some other example.

Comment: I would be grateful! Actually I want to use this repository as boilerplate! https://github.com/jojoldu/freelec-springboot2-webservice

Answer (score 0):

you can also use online tool to create basic building blocks in the below url,

https://start.spring.io/